# What the reason of such output "println" order? How to initialize object in this code?

Tags: java, class

I had this code:

```
class Egg2 {
    protected class Yolk {
        public Yolk() { System.out.println("Egg2.Yolk()");}
        public void f() { System.out.println("Egg2.Yolk.f()");         }
    }
    private Yolk y = new Yolk();
    public Egg2() { System.out.println("New Egg2()");}
    public void insertYolk(Yolk yy) { y = yy; }
    public void g() { y.f(); }
}

public class BigEgg2 extends Egg2 {
    public class Yolk extends Egg2.Yolk {
        public Yolk() { System.out.println("BigEgg2.Yolk"); }
        public void f() { System.out.println("BigEgg2.Yolk.f()"); }

    }
    public BigEgg2() { insertYolk(new Yolk()); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Egg2 e2 = new BigEgg2();
        e2.g();
    }

}
```

Output is:

```
Egg2.Yolk()
New Egg2()
Egg2.Yolk()
BigEgg2.Yolk
BigEgg2.Yolk.f()
```

**Issue:** now I can't make out how such objects and classes were initialized.
I thought the order should be like this:

1. Create new link e2: Egg2 e2 = new BigEgg2();
2. Go to constructor: public BigEgg2() { insertYolk(new Yolk()); }
3. Because of inheritance compiler go to: public Yolk() { System.out.println("Egg2.Yolk()");}, after that we saw output: Egg2.Yolk();
4. Then compiler invoked this method:  public void insertYolk(Yolk yy) { y = yy; }, where Egg2.Yolk.y = BigEgg2.Yolk.yy (figuratively speaking).
5. At this step I can't figure out why the next output result will be:

   New Egg2()

   Egg2.Yolk()

   BigEgg2.Yolk

What's appearance at this stage?

Why it go like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot is going on when you call a constructor of a class with a superclass constructor, and they both have instance variable initializers.

Your constructor for `BigEgg2` doesn't explicitly call any superclass constructor, so the compiler inserted a call to the default constructor for `Egg2`.  (The same thing applies to the `Egg2` constructor calling the `Object` constructor, but that one doesn't print anything.)

After the call to the superclass constructor completes, instance initializers for the superclass, if any, are run.  This means any instance variables initialized where they are declared.  Here, an instance of `Egg2.Yolk` is created for the instance variable `y`.  This is the first line of output `Egg2.Yolk()`.

Then the body of the superclass constructor is finally executed.  This is the second line of output `New Egg2()`.

The `BigEgg2` class has its own `Yolk` class to instantiate to be passed to `insertYolk` in its own constructor.  It creates a `Yolk` that subclasses the nested class `Yolk` in `Egg2`.  The superclass constructor is called first, which refers to the `Egg2.Yolk` class.  This is the third line of output `Egg2.Yolk()`.  Note that this is the same print statement as the first line of output.

This object of class `BigEgg2.Yolk` is assigned to the instance variable `y` in the superclass method `Egg2.insertYolk`.  This occurs in the body of the `BigEgg2.Yolk` constructor.  The `BigEgg2.Yolk` constructor is responsible for the fourth line of output `BigEgg2.Yolk`.  Note that the `y` variable is now referring to an instance of `BigEgg2.Yolk`.  At this point the execution of the first line of `main` is complete: `Egg2 e2 = new BigEgg2();`.

When you call `e2.g()`, you are calling the `g()` method that `BigEgg2` inherits from `Egg2`, which calls `y.f()`, where `y` is a `Egg2.Yolk`.  Because of polymorphism, the `f()` method in `BigEgg2.Yolk` is called.  This is the fifth line of output `BigEgg2.Yolk.f()`.